# How many sides from diagonals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, contest-math

> A polygon has $100$ diagonals, then it has at least: A-15, B-16, C-17, D-18 Sides?

Using simple patterns, I noticed that all figures (even sides) have $\frac{n}{2}$ sides for $n$ diagonals; this makes me believe that there must be $50$ sides, the answer $18$ seems right then?

But it cannot be $<50$ right?

Comment: What are the diagonals of a polygon ? all the lines joining 2 vertices but the borders of the polygon ? (assumed convex ?). If yes, it is a combinatorial problem, isn't it ? :-)

Comment: an n-gon has at most $\binom n2-n=\frac 12 n(n-1)$ diagonals.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET, this was pasted word-for-word, I cannot tell you anything here unfortunately. But, will it make a difference? The value $18$ still seems too low.

Comment: too mee, 18*15/2 is not too low ;-)

Comment: @WW1: please give your definition of diagonal for a n-gone.

Comment: To build on what others have said: The regular pentagon $ABCDE$ has the diagonals $AC, AD, BD, BE,$ and $CE$. The regular hexagon $ABCDEF$ has $AC, AD, AE, BD, BE, BF, CE, CF,$ and $DF$ as diagonals. You reach 100 diagonals pretty quickly this way.

Comment: @WW1 $(^n_2)-n=\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$

Comment: @Aniket that is correct, I tried to edit but I was too late

Comment: so, delete it ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Assuming a diagonal is a segment that joins two distinct nonadjacent vertices, then each vertex is involved in $n-3$ diagonals.  Thus the total number of diagonals is  $\frac{n\cdot(n-3)}{2}$.

Comment: And in particular there is no convex polygon that has exactly $100$ diagonals.

Comment: But if one defines a diagonal to mean a line segment between two different vertices whose interior points are all in the interior of the polygon, then one could use a convex 16-gon where four nonadjacent corners have angles of 180°.

Comment: I would say in the wording of the question, what is sought is the least number of sides a polygon might have in order to have at least 100 diagonals.  One could certainly expand the problem to make 'tricky' cases more of a factor.  We should have an agreed upon definition of diagonal also for the problem.

Comment: a 16 sided polygon has at most 104 diagonals but if it includes 2 sets of 3 co-linear points then it could have exactly 100

Comment: I think it depends on how you define diagonal.